# Confusion about UIGestures - message receivers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't understand what I am doing wrong

Why does `velocityInView:self.view` & `locationInView` sends to `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but not to `UIPanGestureRecognizer`?

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *cursorMode =  [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
    cursorMode.minimumPressDuration = 0.35;
    [self.Row2View addGestureRecognizer:cursorMode];


- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    float position = round([gesture locationInView:self.view].x);
    NSLog(@"%f", position);

    CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:self.view];

    if(velocity.x* _lastGestureVelocity.x > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture went in the same direction");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture went in the opposite direction");
    }

    _lastGestureVelocity = velocity;
}
```

**Error:** *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILongPressGestureRecognizer velocityInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001b0300'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix by either creating `cursorMode` as a pan gesture recognizer (which I think is what you mean), or renaming the `pan:` method (to longPress:), and parameterizing with a long press gr.

As it stands now, the code allocates a long press gr:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *cursorMode = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
```

But casts the parameter to `pan:` as a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, sending it the `velocityInView:` message.  This will crash at runtime because, as you point out, it is being sent to a long press gr.

**EDIT** - Based on comments, it seems the functional goal is to track motion after a long press is recognized.  This can be done without the use of a pan gesture, by keeping location state yourself:

```
@property(assign,nonatomic) CGPoint lastLocation;

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *cursorMode =  [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
cursorMode.minimumPressDuration = 0.35;
[self.Row2View addGestureRecognizer:cursorMode];

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    CGPoint location = [gr locationInView:gr.view];
    // you can compute the change in location like this
    CGPoint delta = CGPointMake(location.x-self.lastLocation.x, location.y-self.lastLocation.y);

    // do whatever you want with location or delta, then at the end...
    self.lastLocation = location;
}
```

Please notice that the choice of coordinate system is the result of which view we pass to `locationInView:`.  By passing `gr.view` as the suggested code does, we will be tracking the pan *within* the view that's getting the gesture.  Another common choice of coordinates is to track the pan within the view's superview.

Comment: My intent is to fire up UIPanGestureRecognizer after UILongPress, how can I achieve it if my *cursorMode will be UIPanGestureRec?

Comment: What I was waiting from my code: 1) Receive LongPress 2) LongPress Triggers UIPanGestureRecognizer and 3) UIpanGestureRecognaizer is now a receiver , but not UILongPress.

Comment: @Edgar - see edit.  this is possible with just one gr.  You could try to make two work, but its trickier.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to track both recognizers, but ignore the callback from the Pan until the LongPress has been recognized.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez possibly, not sure if it's better. you'll still be tracking state in order to get the two gestures to work together.

Answer (score 0):

`-(CGPoint)velocityInView:(UIView *)view` is a method of `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but not of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` or `UIGestureRecognizer`, that's why your app is crashing.

Comment: Yes, I know , but how can I send `velocityInview` to `UIPanGestureRec`?